# Button requiring 2 clicks to work. - Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code is in this jsfiddle snippet below. Whenever I press the remove button, it requires 2 clicks to remove the boxes that were originally generated with html. If I have added them, then those boxes work properly with one click. The problem lies with these boxes that are made through the markup.

Link to the code : [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tcjuxqdn/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .box-container {
                display: flex;
            }

            .box-item {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                background: orangered;
                margin: 0 10px;
            }

            .activated {
                background: dodgerblue;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box-container">
            <span class="1 box-item"></span>
            <span class="2 box-item"></span>
            <span class="3 box-item"></span>
        </div>

        <button id="add">Add</button>
        <button id="remove">Remove</button>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

JS CODE

```
const boxContainer = document.getElementById("box-container");
const boxItems = document.getElementsByClassName("box-item");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const removeBtn = document.getElementById("remove");

function Box(element) {
    this.__el = element;
    this.activated = true;
}

Box.prototype.init = function() {
    this.activateBox();
    this.__el.addEventListener("click", this.toggleActivation.bind(this));
};

Box.prototype.logger = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

Box.prototype.activateBox = function() {
    if (this.activated) {
        this.__el.classList.add("activated");
    }
};

Box.prototype.deactivateBox = function() {
    if (!this.activated) {
        this.__el.classList.remove("activated");
    }
};

Box.prototype.toggleActivation = function() {
    this.__el.classList.toggle("activated");
    return (this.activated = !this.activated);
};

let box = [];

for (let i = 0; i < boxItems.length; i++) {
    box[i] = new Box(boxItems[i]);
    box[i].init();
}

const addBox = function() {
    const node = document.createElement("span");
    node.classList.add("box-item", "activated");
    boxContainer.appendChild(node);
};

function removeBox() {
    boxContainer.removeChild(boxContainer.lastChild);
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBox);
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", removeBox);
```

PS: I have checked other 2 questions that have the same title, but they don't solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your HTML includes *text nodes* between the `.box-item`s:

```
    <div id="box-container">
        <span class="1 box-item"></span>
        <span class="2 box-item"></span>
        <span class="3 box-item"></span>
    </div>
```

So, when you call

```
boxContainer.removeChild(boxContainer.lastChild);
```

If a parent's last child node is a text node, that text node will be selected when you use `lastChild`. That's not what you want - you don't want to select the text nodes. You only want to remove the `<span>` elements, so you might remove the last item in the `.children` instead:

```
const { children } = boxContainer;
boxContainer.removeChild(children[children.length - 1]);
```

Or, more elegantly, select the `lastElementChild` property, thanks to Andre's comment:

```
boxContainer.removeChild(boxContainer.lastElementChild);
```

(quite confusingly, the final index of `children` is *not* the same thing as the node returned by `lastChild`)

```js
const boxContainer = document.getElementById("box-container");
const boxItems = document.getElementsByClassName("box-item");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const removeBtn = document.getElementById("remove");

function Box(element) {
  this.__el = element;
  this.activated = true;
}

Box.prototype.init = function() {
  this.activateBox();
  this.__el.addEventListener("click", this.toggleActivation.bind(this));
};

Box.prototype.logger = function() {
  console.log(this);
};

Box.prototype.activateBox = function() {
  if (this.activated) {
    this.__el.classList.add("activated");
  }
};

Box.prototype.deactivateBox = function() {
  if (!this.activated) {
    this.__el.classList.remove("activated");
  }
};

Box.prototype.toggleActivation = function() {
  this.__el.classList.toggle("activated");
  return (this.activated = !this.activated);
};

let box = [];

for (let i = 0; i < boxItems.length; i++) {
  box[i] = new Box(boxItems[i]);
  box[i].init();
}

const addBox = function() {
  const node = document.createElement("span");
  node.classList.add("box-item", "activated");
  boxContainer.appendChild(node);
};

function removeBox() {
  boxContainer.removeChild(boxContainer.lastElementChild);
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBox);
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", removeBox);
```

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box-item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: orangered;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.activated {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <span class="1 box-item"></span>
  <span class="2 box-item"></span>
  <span class="3 box-item"></span>
</div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Or, you can just change the HTML such that there are no text nodes:

```
<div id="box-container"><span class="1 box-item"></span><span class="2 box-item"></span><span class="3 box-item"></span></div>
```

```js
const boxContainer = document.getElementById("box-container");
const boxItems = document.getElementsByClassName("box-item");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const removeBtn = document.getElementById("remove");

function Box(element) {
  this.__el = element;
  this.activated = true;
}

Box.prototype.init = function() {
  this.activateBox();
  this.__el.addEventListener("click", this.toggleActivation.bind(this));
};

Box.prototype.logger = function() {
  console.log(this);
};

Box.prototype.activateBox = function() {
  if (this.activated) {
    this.__el.classList.add("activated");
  }
};

Box.prototype.deactivateBox = function() {
  if (!this.activated) {
    this.__el.classList.remove("activated");
  }
};

Box.prototype.toggleActivation = function() {
  this.__el.classList.toggle("activated");
  return (this.activated = !this.activated);
};

let box = [];

for (let i = 0; i < boxItems.length; i++) {
  box[i] = new Box(boxItems[i]);
  box[i].init();
}

const addBox = function() {
  const node = document.createElement("span");
  node.classList.add("box-item", "activated");
  boxContainer.appendChild(node);
};

function removeBox() {
  boxContainer.removeChild(boxContainer.lastChild);
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBox);
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", removeBox);
```

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box-item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: orangered;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.activated {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container"><span class="1 box-item"></span><span class="2 box-item"></span><span class="3 box-item"></span></div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Comment: You also could use `lastElementChild` instead of `lastChild`. That'll target the last Element.

Comment: "quite confusingly, the final index of children is not the same thing as the node returned by lastChild"... lol. Very confusing... but true.

Comment: @Andre Oh, cool, I didn't know about that, thanks! I searched for other `last`s on [Node.lastChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) but didn't find any, so I thought it didn't exist, but the property is on [ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild), not `Node`.

Comment: Saw the loophole, always something new to learn...thanks !! ^^